# Replace row values in data.table using 'by' and conditions

Tags: r, replace, conditional-statements, data.table, subset

I am trying to replace certain row values in a column according to conditions in another column, within a grouping.

**EDIT**: edited to highligh the recursive nature of the problem.

E.g.

```
DT = data.table(y=rep(c(1,3), each = 3)
            ,v=as.numeric(c(1,2,4,4,5,8))
            ,x=as.numeric(rep(c(9:11),each=2)),key=c("y","v"))
DT
   y v  x
1: 1 1  9
2: 1 2  9
3: 1 4 10
4: 3 4 10
5: 3 5 11
6: 3 8 11
```

Within each 'y', I then want to replace values of 'x' where 'v' has an observation v+t (e.g. t = 3),  with 2222 (or in reality the results of a function) to following result:

```
   y v  x
1: 1 1  9
2: 1 2  9
3: 1 4 2222
4: 3 4 10
5: 3 5 11
6: 3 8 2222
```

I have tried the following, but to no avail.

```
  DT[which((v-3) %in% v), x:= 2222, y][]
```

And it mysteriously (?) results in:

```
   y v  x
1: 1 1  9
2: 1 2  9
3: 1 4 2222
4: 3 4 2222
5: 3 5 2222
6: 3 8 2222
```

Running:

```
DT[,print(which((v-3) %in% v)), by =y]
```

Indicates that it does the correct indexing within the groups, but what happens from (or the lack thereof) I don't understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try using `replace` (which could have some overhead because it copies whole `x`)

```
 DT[, x:=replace(x, which(v %in% (v+3)), 2222), by=y]
 #   y v    x
 #1: 1 1    9
 #2: 1 2    9
 #3: 1 4 2222
 #4: 3 4   10
 #5: 3 5   11
 #6: 3 8 2222
```

Alternatively, you could create a logical index column and then do the assignment in the next step

```
 DT[,indx:=v %in% (v+3), by=y][(indx), x:=2222, by=y][, indx:=NULL]
 DT
 #   y v    x
 #1: 1 1    9
 #2: 1 2    9
 #3: 1 4 2222
 #4: 3 4   10
 #5: 3 5   11
 #6: 3 8 2222
```

Or slightly modifying your own approach using `.I` in order to create an index

```
indx <- DT[, .I[which((v-3) %in% v)], by = y]$V1
DT[indx, x := 2222]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! It did work, but I realised my example was to simple and didn't really catch the nature of my problem so I edited it accordingly. By the way, what do L do? I can't seem to understand the purpose of it.

Comment: @EndreGrünerOfstad I don't know where it's documented, but `10L` is the integer, while `10` is a float (and so may be rounded by the computer leading to unexpected results). In this case, it shouldn't matter, since `v` is already a float column.

Comment: @EndreGrünerOfstad  I used `10L` as the class of the `v` was integer and data.table will throw warning/errors when the class don't match.  If it was numeric, it would have been just `10`.

Comment: @Frank The OP changed the example.  It was previously `integer` class.

Comment: Oh, just noticed: the `by=y` should make no difference here, right?

Comment: @Frank It is better to specify the `by`, but I forgot at that time.  It won't make any difference here.

Comment: Oh sorry, not sure if you took my meaning: `DT[x=='a',v:=10L]` does the same thing, I meant.

Comment: @Frank Sure, it does and is faster. I was trying to emulate the OP's code.  I am not sure I understand the edit output.

Comment: @EndreGrünerOfstad  I didn't understand how you got the expected output with `9, 10, 11` etc for the `x` column while there is only a single assignment with `2222`.  Your code results in error `DT[which((v-3) %in% v), x:= 2222, y][]#
Error in `[.data.table`(DT, which((v - 3) %in% v), `:=`(x, 2222), y)`

Comment: Hi, the edits were done in a hurry before I had to leave for a meeting, so there were  some hiccups in copy-pasting from R. Should be correct  now. Is the question understandable? If an observation have a correspondence t = 3 time steps away, change the value in that row in column x.

Comment: @EndreGrünerOfstad  Please check my updated answer.  I think it should match now with the expected edit.

Comment: Odd, question... I would go with `indx <- DT[,.I[which((v-3) %in% v)], by = y]$V1 ; DT[indx, x := 2222]` but I guess your solution works too.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks, I was confused by the results of  `DT[v %in% (v+3), .N, by=y]` and `DT[,v %in% (v+3), by=y]`

Comment: Despite any overhead, the operation was repeated 3 times (using different values of t) on >800,000 in quite a decent time :)